# php Exception.getMessage() always returns nothing

Tags: php, exception

When I catch an exception in php and try to output some details, getMessage() invariably returns nothing. If I do a var_dump(), I see the message that I would like to display. What am I doing wrong?

```
                try
                {
                    ...
                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    echo "<p>Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>"; 
                    return;
                }
```

if I do var_dump($e) I get the following output:

> object(ETWSException)#735 (10) { ["errorCode":protected]=> int(401)
>   ["errorMessage":protected]=> string(226) "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 18:26:30 GMT Server: Apache WWW-Authenticate:
>   OAuth realm=https://etws.etrade.com/,oauth_problem=token_expired
>   Content-Length: 995 Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 "
>   ["httpCode":protected]=> NULL ["message":protected]=> string(0) ""
>   ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=>
>   int(0) ["file":protected]=>[snip!]

I would think that getMessage() should display the contents of errorMessage.

Well I tried $e->getErrorMessage() and *that* displays the expected message. Searching google for php exception getErrorMessage does not seem to show anything useful (all pages only seem to mention getMessage, not getErrorMessage). What gives?

Comment: Documentation is showing getMessage()... http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php

That's very odd.

Comment: I know... I think I'm going nuts.

Comment: can you do a ```php -v``` ? I tested on my box (5.6.12) and getMessage is the correct function name.

Comment: So you got an object of type `ETWSException` here – most likely that’s a class that extends the PHP exception class. Go look it up in the documentation of whatever it is you are using there, or look at the source code, to see exactly what properties and methods it provides …

Comment: @CBroe is probably correct. Here is a test showing that getMessage is the correct function for Exception in all recent PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/hUkjb

Comment: Right. I think I had the same issue with a non ETWSException -- but I'll have to update this question when I encounter it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The e-trade exception class is a mess. It implements its own constructor and does not set the correct values for the standard `Exception`. It expects you to use `$e->getErrorMessage()` to get the message.

```
<?php
/**
 * E*TRADE PHP SDK
 *
 * @package     PHP-SDK
 * @version     1.1
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 E*TRADE FINANCIAL Corp.
 *
 */

class ETWSException extends Exception
{
    protected $errorCode;
    protected $errorMessage;
    protected $httpCode;
    /**
     * Constructor ETWSException
     *
     */
    public function __construct($errorMessage, $errorCode = null, $httpCode = null, Exception $previous = null) {
        $this->errorMessage     = $errorMessage;
        $this->errorCode        = $errorCode;
        $this->httpCode         = $httpCode;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the errorCode property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Integer }
     *
     */
    public function getErrorCode() {
        return $this->errorCode;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the errorMessage property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *
     */
    public function getErrorMessage() {
        return $this->errorMessage;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the value of the httpStatusCode property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *
     */
    public function getHttpCode() {
        return $this->httpCode;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here. First, if you look at the var_dump of $e, the message index is empty. Thus, you are getting nothing back when you use getMessage. Second, the exception thrown is not a standard PHP exception. It is written by the API you are using and you need to read its documentation to figure out how to correctly handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
["message":protected]=> string(0) ""
```

Is your issue

```
get_class_methods($e)
```

may expose some more